# Sort alphabetically numbers in a row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to thank you for your patience.

Initially I need an answer in **PHP or Javascript or jQuery**.

I have a .txt file with more than 800 lines, and each line has a number of numbers, for example:

> 01-54-32-06-02-28-50-67 - ... ( +/- 32 numbers)
>   32-50-02-04-16-21-17-11 - ... ( +/- 38 numbers)
>   ... ( +/- 800 lines)

As you can see each line has a lot of numbers, separated by '-'. And the file has many lines. What's a ridiculous amount.

Would leave those numbers in ordered lines? Example:

> 01-02-06-28-32-50-54-67-...
>   02-04-11-16-17-21-32-50-...
>   ...

Did not want to register in the database (for PHP), or do it all manually. Would take too long, maybe I ages to fix it all. **:)**

Would any tool to sort through .txt file. I was thinking something, example :

> /01-54-32-06-02-28-50-67-...
>   /02-50-02-04-16-21-17-11-...
>   ...

The '/' would be the trigger to begin organizing the line. I do not know I'm talking nonsense.

I managed to find a similar tool. This tool it commands all the numbers, leaving everything on the same line. What I do not want.
  http://www.textfixer.com/tools/alphabetical-order.php

The code of the page up came from here:
  http://www.overset.com/2008/09/01/javascript-natural-sort-algorithm-with-unicode-support/

Please I need an answer. Even if it is **'Man, do not have as only NASA to save you'**, I need a help.

Thank you very much.

Comment: read from file, loop by line, explode by - sort array, write back to file.

Comment: I think if it were me, I'd do a combination of sorting with code and with database. I'd open the file, read from file one line at a time. For each line, explode at hyphen and do an array sort and then implode it back. Then I'd insert that line into a db table. End result is all the rows are in the table and the numbers in the rows are sorted. Then I'd do a query for all with a `sort by columnname` and let the db sort the rows. because.. doing a row sort with files only can be kind of a pita, esp if your file is large

Comment: Thanks for answering Dagon :), forgot to mention I'm not very good at programming. Could you show me how do I read the file and return it even perhaps an example? It seems too complicated. That's why I ask for help.

Comment: break it down step by step and google for each phrase. "php read file", "php explode", "php array sort" etc.. you need to make an effort to write your own code and ask for help if you get stuck on something in particular. Nobody is just going to write it for you unless you throw money at them

Comment: You could use [`that tool`](http://www.textfixer.com/tools/alphabetical-order.php) then in your favorite text editor, do a search and replace for `-` and replace with a line break/carriage return. However, there are scripts/functions that will do it in one run.

Comment: Actually, [`that tool`](http://www.textfixer.com/tools/alphabetical-order.php) does have that option in there, where you choose `-` for the `Input Format Options` and then choose `Line break` from `Output Format Options` if that's the result you're looking to get. It will sort from the smallest to largest number and put them all on a new line.

Comment: actually, are you looking to sort just the numbers in the rows, or ALSO sort the actual rows?

Comment: in order, if it was me, file() foreach() explode() asort() implode() fwrite()

Comment: Actually I want to sort the numbers of the line, not the lines themselves. Now I realized that my example confudiu a bit.

Comment: I'll try to do what 'Dagon' showed. Thanks guys, I'll try to do what I'm told. Do not expect such a quick response. :)

Comment: oh okay well that is significantly easier then; yes, follow Dagon's blueprint. Well, it would be better if you read line by line with fopen() and fread() and a while loop than use file/foreach so that you don't load all the lines in memory at once

Comment: @CrayonViolent 800 lines i was not worried about memory, but it would scale poorly.

Comment: 800 lines doesn't seem like too many. Perhaps you could just paste them in the textarea of [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wkju9/).

Comment: I want to give a huge thanks to everyone who helped me, both those showed me that studying is everything and others who have had the patience :). Anyway, thank you very much. Hugs to everyone who needs it. Like the Brazilians say 'Que Deus abençoe vocês' (God bless you). Tchau para todos (Bye for everyone). * Vote for me, I have no reputation :(. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script will sift through each line from the file and sort it.

This can consume alot of resources if files is really really big.

You can use MySQL database for simple line by line sorting instead of taking from file.

Let me know if you need help in anything else.

```
<?php
// Getting Data from a file 'data.txt' into $content variable
$content = file_get_contents('data.txt');

// $info - array for storing final info
$info = array();

// Putting all lines in $info - put / at the end of every line or change the delimeter from '/' to anything else
$info = explode('/', $content);

// Going through All lines one by one - Sorting it and putting it back on the array
foreach ($info as $key => $value) {
    $number = explode('-', $value);
    sort($number);
    $info[$key] = implode('-', $number);
}

// Echo - Save to File

print_r($info); //Echo'ing result

file_put_contents('final.txt', implode("\n/",$info)); //Putting it into file
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, if you could would give you a hug. * Vote for me, I have no reputation :(. Thanks

Comment: @brcrash Sorry, can't do that. To get upvotes, your question would need to include your attempted solutions and an explanation of how your results differ from the intended results, rather than just describing what you'd like the script to do. You'll be lucky if the question doesn't get closed. I only voted to leave open because a good answer was already posted. Please read this [advice on how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Since you don't have enough rep, though, I did upvote the answer for you. ;)